# How to take care of this orchid

Tags: houseplants, flowers, orchids

Can someone please give me some advices on how to care of this kind of orchid. I never had orchids before so I would like to know
a) if it needs a bigger pot
b) what type of soil is best for its needs
c) where should I keep it (does it prefer light or shade)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plant is a *Phaleonopsis* (common name moth orchid) and it's  one of the very few easy care orchids. It needs bright light, but no direct sunlight; they do well on windowsills. They do not need a lot of water because they are epiphytes, so just give a little once or  maybe twice a week if your home is very hot, less if it's cooler. Repotting can be done, but not while it's in flower, and it's best to wait until the roots are lifting well above the pot rim. These are often potted just into bark, or sometimes a specialist orchid potting mix, but never repot into ordinary potting soil. Further info here https://www.ourhouseplants.com/plants/phalaenopsis

Comment: Bamboo is correct; the most common death for these is from too frequent watering.